# Search string by exact word in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system that searches for company. I want that when a user searches for "Demo", all records that have "Demo" will be returned, like "The Demo", "Demo Inc.", etc. I don't want those records like "Democratic", "Demolition", etc. I think you get my point.

Right now, my working query looks something like this:

```
select * from table where company LIKE "Demo%"
```

But that really doesn't hit my requirement. I also tried this one:

```
select * from table where company RLIKE "[[:<:]]demo[[:>:]]"
```

The only problem on that one is that it eliminates the possibility of index on my company field. So it searches really slow. I have over a million records right now. Any idea how to do it? If it can't be done in mysql, any idea if it's possible in PHP? Thanks!

Comment: If you're always getting an exact value which you wish to search by, ie. You're always going to want to search for *The Demo* would it not be best to search: `WHERE company='The Demo'`?

Comment: You can look for full text search, I feel it will give you desired result

Comment: As you cant use MySQL RLIKE because of speed , do it in PHP, fist select all that has word DEMO, than in PHP you use regex to catch ones that are boundary words. Let me know if you need a sample code

Answer (score 2):

Create an Full text index, and then you can search more easy.

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT INDEX fulltext_index;


SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (company) AGAINST ('+Demo' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) and the `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` word boundary markers:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    company REGEXP '[[:<:]]Demo[[:>:]]';
```

Another Solution

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    company REGEXP '(^|[[:space:]])Demo([[:space:]]|$)';
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/ENK60102)

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark as per my comment. If you're always going to get an exact match criteria. would it not be best to perform a standard select query?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE company='The Demo'
```

Or for practical:

```
   $Search = $_GET['company'];
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE company='$Search'
```

Obviously use best practices when working with user input & Queries.

The results drawn will be either the rows found to have *The Demo*, *the demo* would be returned or nothing.

---

If you do not always have an exact match. You could again, use $_GET with an appended value ie $_GET['Exact'] & have two different functions:

```
function ExactMatch ($DB,$Company){
  /* 
    Query to get exact match as exampled 
  */

}
function NotExact($DB,$Company){
  /*
   Query using LIKE syntax 
  */
}
```

and validate:

```
if (isset($_GET['Exact'])){
  if ($_GET['Exact'] === 1){
    ExactMatch($DB,$_GET['Company']);
  }else{
    NotExact($DB,$_GET['Company'])
  }
}
```

Also, a possible read on DBA.stackexchange:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/how-to-speed-up-queries-on-a-large-220-million-rows-table-9-gig-data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE company LIKE "% Demo %"
    OR company LIKE "Demo %"
    OR company="Demo";
```

Comment: also make sure that company column is indexed. so make the column index. and also use varchar instead of text.

Comment: This won't catch 'The Demo Company' or "The Demo" , but this may work adding more OR variations

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why 1M is a problem I just tested on my laptop MySQL MyISAM that has also a company but it is 250K rows and it took 3.3 ms , and the field is not indexed. can you try folowing

```
$search='Demo';
$regex="/\b$search\b/i";
$sql = "select * from table where company like '%$search%';
//... get the results
foreach($results as $companyName){
 if(preg_match($regex,$companyName,$match)){
    //here you got a match 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is create a fulltext index:

```
create fulltext index `i_company` on `table`(`company`);
```

Then you can search as:

```
select * from `table` where match(company) against ('Demo');
```

Read more about [mysql full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

Depending on your MySQL version, Full text index is available for MyISAM in version 5.5 or less, and is available for InnoDB since 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

To search exact word from string, use the below query

```
select
*
from tablename 
where column_name regexp '(^|[[:space:]])wordyouwanttosearch([[:space:]]|$)';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this it may help ya..

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE company LIKE "%Demo%";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try testing for a space at both sides:

```
select * from table where company LIKE "Demo %" OR company LIKE "% Demo"
```

However, as you have stated you need to make use of your indexes and anything with a leading wildcard `%` won't use the indexes.

### So, I think that you need to implement some kind of pre-processing on your search columns, something along the lines of:

Pre-process your record names:

- Use a [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) algorithm on all the record names in your database
- Store the stemmed words in one table (**stemmed_words**)
- Record the number of occurrences of the stemmed word against the record id (**record_index**)

Then when the user searches:

- Use a stemming algorithm on the search term words
- Query your tables to find the result with the most frequently used stemmed word

Example **stemmed_words** Table columns:

```
id, stemmed_word  // Eg. 1 (auto generated), "Demo"
```

Example **record_index** Table columns:

```
record_id, stemmed_word_id, occurrence_count // Eg. 1 (auto generated), 1 (ID of "Demo" in stemmed_words table), 2 (2 occurrences)
```

[Here's a basic tutorial to get you started with stemming and word counts](http://www.codediesel.com/php/porter-stemming-in-search/)

Comment: For which example?  It would work for "Demo", "The Demo", "Demo inc" and not for "Demolition" and "Democratic"

Comment: As I said, I have over million records and it's growing by the day. Putting a wildcard before the word kills the index on my company field.

Comment: True, it won't use the index with a leading `%`

Comment: Ok, so the mysql route isn't much use here.  Please see my update - hopefully that will lead you in the right direction for creating your own index for basic search.