# MySQL - How to search for exact word match in a column of sentence?

Tags: mysql, search

I have a MySQL table with a list of sentences such as:

```
id | Sentence 
---+---------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Come On Boys, You Can do it my boy.
 2 | Everything is possible, impossible itself says I am possible.
 3 | Boys I know possible solutions are good!
 4 | Possible solutions are all failed its also possible
```

I have to search on `Sentence` column exact word like `possible`.

There are some condition :

1. Searching word can't be prefix or suffix of any word.

   - Searching word `possible` , `impossible` is incorrect.
2. Punctuation mark can be before or after the word.Ex: `!boy` or `boy,`
3. No case sensitive means for `possible` `Possible` is correct.

I try a query but it is not working

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Sentence LIKE '%".$search."%'");
```

Possible punctuation mark are `,.!?;-`

I need a working solution. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can use a regexp.

Comment: fulltext index and search is what you are looking for.

Comment: Shadow: No, see condition (ii) and (iii).

Comment: Words indexed by the fulltext index will not include punctuation marks. iii depends on the collation used, but by default the search is done in a case insensitive mode.

Comment: @Fred-ii- pls check out the duplicate link and wield your hammer if you think it is appropriate

Comment: @Shadow Seeing [this comment by the OP...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140920/mysql-how-to-search-for-exact-word-match-in-a-colomn-of-sentence?noredirect=1#comment73359043_43140992) in an answer, uses the same code (somewhat) from the possible dupe. The OP really should have spend more time researching this and trying different methods, IMO anyway. But.. .that dupe may be it. *Thinking............*

Comment: @Fred-ii- the OP also said in a comment above that fulltext index would not satisfy conditions ii and iii, which clearly indicate that he did not properly check out fulltext indexes (or did not describe the criteria completely).

Comment: I really don't know 'fulltext indexes' what is this means ?

Comment: And I see this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql  but this solution won't satisfy my condition I think that .

Comment: @Fred-ii- since the duplicate topic has the same answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/42038254/5389997) as  Tim's, you can safely mark it as a duplicate. Or use the link in Rafaels answer below. Same difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE Sentence REGEXP '[[:<:]]possible[[:>:]]'
--                       ^^^            ^^^ word boundaries
```

This would correspond to matching `possible` surrounded by a word boundary.  Note in the demo that punctuation counts as a word boundary.

Also note that MySQL's `REGEXP` is case insensitive, so the above should match `possible` or `Possible`.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: This will not work for condition (ii).

Comment: @AbinashGhosh *"This will not work for condition"* - I find that rather hard to believe.

Comment: @Fred-ii- My initial answer neglected the case for punctuation.  Hence, Abinash's comment was valid initially.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My comment was based on what I saw before the edit.

Comment: Does punctuation count as a word boundary?  Time to learn something new perhaps.

Comment: @Tim I don't know about this

Comment: If my answer fails for certain cases, then reveal those cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE Sentence REGEXP '[^\\d\\w]possible[^\\d\\w]'
```

This takes every word `possible` surrounded by any word or number.

Be carefull with case sensitivity.

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: So what did he ask for ?

Comment: `There are some condition` ... read the question

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, sentence VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO tmp (sentence) VALUES ('Come On Boys, You Can do it my boy.');
INSERT INTO tmp (sentence) VALUES ('Everything is possible, impossible itself says I am possible.');
INSERT INTO tmp (sentence) VALUES ('Boys I know possible solutions are good!');
INSERT INTO tmp (sentence) VALUES ('Possible solutions are all failed its also possible');

SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE sentence REGEXP '[[:<:]]impossible[[:>:]]';
```

This is duplicate: [Search for "whole word match" in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656951/search-for-whole-word-match-in-mysql)

Comment: If you believe a question to be a duplicate, don't copy-paste answers but flag as duplicate instead.

Comment: Can't do it atm, and this wasn't copy & paste btw.